# Make a histogram in r based on values of another variable

Tags: r

I have a small, 2-variable data frame:

```
month <- c("january","february","march","april","may")
data <- c(10,20,30,20,10)
df <- data.frame(month = month, data = data)
```

which looks like this:

```
     month data
1  january   10
2 february   20
3    march   30
4    april   20
5      may   10
```

I want to make a histogram plot based on this data, in which the columns would represent the "data" values in each month, i.e. a "10" column on the x-axis "january" mark, a "20" column on "february" mark and so on.

How do I do that?
I've tried all kinds of things with the "hist" function - to no avail.

Comment: You don't want an histogram, you want a barplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R:

```
barplot(dt$data, names.arg=dt$month)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want good graphics, you can do the same with ggplot2 like this

```
library(ggplot2)
month <- c("january","february","march","april","may")
month <- factor(month,levels=month,ordered=TRUE)
data <- c(10,20,30,20,10)
df <- data.frame(month = month, data = data)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(month,data,fill=month))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- p+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

Answer (score 0):

With barp{plotrix}:

```
month <- c("january","february","march","april","may")
data <- c(10,20,30,20,10)

library(plotrix)
barp(data, names.arg=month)
```

[image]